# getting an exception when refreshing the configuration in memory on change to external config file

Tags: c#, configuration, windows-services, app-config

I have a windows service which reads the config settings from an external file which is located at a different path than the path to the executable for the windows service. the windows service uses a FileSystemWatcher to monitor the changes to the external config file and when it the config file is changed, it should refresh the settings in memory by reading the updated settings from the config file. but this is where I am getting an exception "ConfigurationErrorsException" and the message is "An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for appSettings: The process cannot access the file 'M:\somefolder\WindowsService1.Config' because it is being used by another process." and the inner exception is actually "IOException" with same message. here is the code. I am not sure what is wrong with the code. Please help.

```
protected void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(ConfigSectionName);
    WriteToEventLog(ConfigKeyCheck);

    if (FileChanged != null)
        FileChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void WriteToEventLog(string key)
{
    if (EventLog.SourceExists(ServiceEventSource))
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceEventSource,
                            string.Format("key:{0}, value:{1}", key, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]));                
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the config file changing?  Is a user editing the file or is an application updating it?  If a user is editing it, they could use a non-locking editor like notepad++, and if an application is editing it, it should also try to avoid locking the file.  In any case, my answer should help you deal with file locking issues.

Comment: edited by user not application. I used visual studio to update the config file (the application is still in development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect that IO exceptions occur if trying to re-read the configuration section upon every detected change.  For example, the file could be locked (as in your case), or write could be only partially completed.  You should just put the code in a `try`/`catch` block, catch `IOException`s (and maybe more), and retry the refresh later, perhaps after a timer elapses.

Comment: it works now, thanks. not sure how ASP.NET handles this for web.config files, because those settings are automatically refreshed without having to write any code and don't throw any locking exceptions, not sure if uses a timer as well.

Answer (score 0):

changed the code as per Jacob's suggestion and it works now (I tried catching only IOException, but it didn't work). if exception occurs more than 3 times, then the exception is swallowed, but any subsequent reads from config file will throw unhandled exception forcing the service to stop. hopefully that situation won't occur.

```
private void WriteToEventLog(string key)
{
    try
    {
        if (EventLog.SourceExists(ServiceEventSource))
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceEventSource,
                                string.Format("key:{0}, value:{1}", key, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]));
            _configReadCount = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)); //sleep for a minute and try again
        _configReadCount++;
        if (_configReadCount <= 3) //try 3 times 
            WriteToEventLog(ConfigKeyCheck);
    }

}
```